# Бесконечный скроллинг постов из vk Api

Tags: vkontakte-api

```
     [PHP]<?php 
    $url = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=extrawebdev&access_token=3195e9e93195e9e93115aff35931c30219331953195e9e9697cc67864e1f0c35fe7c074&count=100"); 
    $response = json_decode($url ,true); 
    ?>
    <div class="masonry">

    <?php
    for($i=1;$i< $response['response'][$i];$i++){
    echo
    "<div class='item'> 
    ".date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $response['response'][$i]['date'])."<br><br>
    ".$response['response'][$i]['text']."
    <img src='".$response['response'][$i]['attachment']['photo']['src_big']."'></div>";
    }
    ?>
    [/PHP]

Получаю json массив, вывожу его на страницу, но вот как сделать бесконечный скроллинг не пойму.
```

Само задание:
Сделать страницу (SPA),  для отображения записей со стены ВКонтакте, получаемые из апи с помощью https://vk.com/dev/wall.get, например таким запросом:

https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?domain=extrawebdev&access_token=3195e9e93195e9e93115aff35931c30219331953195e9e9697cc67864e1f0c35fe7c074&count=20

Требования:

Отображение записей  в виде плиток  (картинка если есть и заголовок со ссылкой на оригинальную запись)
опционально, если к записи прикреплена ссылка, то использовать ее для заголовка.

Должна присутствовать навигация по страницам (вперед/назад) 
опционально вместо пагинации бесконечный скролинг

Comment: Что имеете в виду под бесконечным скроллингом? Дозагрузку на лету более старых постов?

Comment: Насколько я понял сначало загружается допустим 12 постов, после подгружается по мере подкрутки.